# Is it possible to pass "signals" to another console program?

Tags: c, windows, gcc

**My aim:** I want to pass a signal (int-type variable) to another **running** console program.

**My idea:** Write the data to the disk, and read the data by the other console program.

**Possible defect:** Too slow, and not efficient.

Is it able to pass "(self-defined / int-type) signals" to another console program ?

Any suggestion (or a better workaround way) would be appreciated.

Comment: [MSDN: Interprocess Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...

Option 1: Use [`SendMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send a message to the other process' message queue. (Probably not suitable since you said you have a console program, and it probably doesn't have a message queue.)

Option 2: Use [named shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Option 3: Use [a named pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) between the two processes.

Option 4: Use [a UDP or TCP network connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) between the two processes.

Option 1 is the simplest/easiest, but requires that the target process have a running message queue to receive and process the message.

Comment: Well, I've tried the first one just now, but it's a little slower than disk I/O (my idea listed above). :-)

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia Which one did you try? All of these (except possibly the network connection) should be *significantly* faster than disk I/O.

Comment: `SendMessage()`. Maybe I could try larger data later.

Comment: Oh yes!  It's significantly faster than disk I/O on larger data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you actually want to pass between the processes involved. If all you need to do is notify the other process, that something has happend (and the other process has the means to find out about the details itself right after being notified), then a [named event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be what you need.

If you need to share more information, consider [shared memory and mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Of course, you may also consider to go down the COM route. Define an interface for the process, which should receive the "signal" and have it register an object in the [global object table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684004%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The sending process can obtain the instance from the object table and use the interface to perform the notification.

There may be countless other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can also pass any signals to any applications in linux using kill .just see 'man kill' for example sending SIGKILL to keil we can write like ..

kill -9 keil

by using kill -l we can see all signals and their respective numbers. and pass their like this 'kill -n app_name'

Comment: Not suitable for windows.